# Intersection of countable collection of closed intervals

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory

Is the following statement true?

$A\subseteq\mathbb{R}$ closed $\iff$ A is the intersection of a countable collection of closed intervals

For $\impliedby$:

Suppose A is the intersection of a countable collection of closed intervals. The intersection of finite or infinite number of closed sets is closed. So A must be closed.

For $\implies$:

If A is closed, then it can be written as the intersection of arbitrarily many closed intervals. I am not sure if this means that the collection is countable though.

Comment: How is $\{0,1\}$ the intersection of any number of intervals?

Comment: @AsafKaragila, I believe I made a mistake in reasoning. Any intersection of closed intervals gives us a closed set. However, this does not mean that any closed set can be written as the intersection of arbitrarily many closed intervals. Am I correct?

Comment: Well, again, how would you represent $\{0,1\}$ as the intersection of closed intervals? Or $\Bbb N$ for that matter?

Comment: @AsafKaragila, we can't is what I was trying to say! Even though the set you gave me is closed, we cannot write it as the intersection of closed intervals.

Comment: Yes, that is correct. But! Can you prove that rigorously? (Hint: what kind of a set can you get when intersecting two intervals?)

Comment: @AsafKaragila, I can get one of the following three: the empty set $\phi$, a singleton or another interval. Since $\{0,1\}$ is neither the empty set nor a singleton nor an interval, then it cannot be written as the intersection of intervals.

Comment: Yes, and if you want to be technical, both the empty set and a singleton are themselves types of closed intervals.

Comment: @AsafKaragila, I see! Thank you very much. I will try to write a rigorous proof (counter-example that is) to disprove the statement then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The intersection of any collection of closed intervals is either empty or a closed interval. (Just verify that if two points belong to the intersection then any point between these two is also in the intersection). Hence the stated result is false.

Comment: The notion is called order convex. Any intersection of order convex subsets is order convex. So finite sets of more than 1 point, or the Cantor set are counterexamples.